# Accuracy of App Engine Geo Search for large circles?

Tags: google-app-engine, geopoints, great-circle

I'm using App Engine Search to restrict results to those within a defined circle.

```
distance("points", geopoint(%f,%f)) < %d" % (latitude, longitude, radii)
```

For radii of 10s, 100s and 1,000s of metres I am getting correct results.
But for radii of say 400,000 (i.e. 400km) then results outside the define circle are being returned.

Does anyone know that this is a limit of this platform? I find it hard to believe that great circle isn't taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Google has [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8824); reported in Feb 2013 and still present today.
The issue tracker marks its priority as medium.

One suggestion is to look at each result returned and check if it is correct.

It occurs that if you add this corrective step on a Google platform, then you are paying twice for this functionality - once for Google's coding execution to produce the incorrect results set and once for your correction code.

This is a non-trivial work-around as any count of total results can be wildly incorrect (e.g., Google returns 100s of results but the actual number is zero).

And if you have to page results for performance reasons then this bug kills that approach as each page set may not contain any valid results once you have filtered out the invalid ones.

Is this the answer or have I, and others, missed some important detail?